# Unable to Remove Vertical Space Before and After Lists within longtable

Tags: spacing, lists, longtable, enumitem

All the tricks to remove vertical space before and after itemize lists (using enumitem) seem to work well in `table/tabular` environments, but not in `longtable`. The following MWE illustrates the difficulty I'm having to get the First bullet at the same level as the Left item.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lp{4cm}}
Header1  &  Header2  \\
Left item  &  
\compress\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
 \item First bullet
 \item Second bullet
 \item Third bullet
\end{itemize}  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{longtable}[htbp]{lp{12.25cm}}
Header1  &  Header2  \\
Left item  &   
\compress\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
 \item First bullet
 \item Second bullet
 \item Third bullet
\end{itemize}  \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Here, even the `\compress` command fails to remove the space in `longtable`. Note that I need `longtable`, as some of my lists will be quite long and will need to be split. (Also, I'm not sure why I need to specify a fixed width for the second column (`{lp{4cm}}`) instead of `{ll}`.)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the `paralist` package? I personally use the `inparaitem` to solve that problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Left item  &
\noindent\par
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\compress\begin{itemize}
```

It could be better, but that's how it is, sorry.

To answer your second question an `l` entry is like `\mbox` so horizontal mode (LR mode in the LaTeX Book) so does not allow line breaking or display environments like lists.

Comment: Thanks for the second point. As for the first, I was hoping for a more elegant solution (a preamble setting that had eluded me), or an admission that this was a known limitation of longtable that would be fixed shortly.

Comment: Given that you are the author of longtable, I'll take your solution to my main point as definitive. :)

Comment: It's not a longtable feature it comes from the underlying tabular implementation you'll see the same putting a standard latex enumerate in a standard tabular. It's actually quite hard to fix automatically although of course the mess could be hidden in a better looking macro (much as `\arraybackslash` makes the nasty mis-match between tabular and \raggedright almost documentable. (short version: it:s not my fault)