# How to remove vertical space above itemize only inside longtable minipage

Tags: tables, spacing, lists, minipage, pandoc

I'm trying to remove the vertical space above/below `\itemize` lists that appear in a `\longtable`. That is, I'd like these lists to all align to the top of their cells:

[image: bad example]

Answers to similar versions of this problem abound (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114822/itemize-inside-longtable), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114280/how-to-reduce-vertical-space-itemize-environment-inside-table), and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94116/unable-to-remove-vertical-space-before-and-after-lists-within-longtable), for example). All the solutions involve editing the table by hand, adding various `\vspace` or other commands.

I am generating my table from a Markdown file with pandoc, though, have have no control over the table output, so modifying the resulting table isn't possible. Here's a MWE.

Given this Markdown file:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 

: Sample grid table.

+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Fruit         | Price         | Advantages         |
+===============+===============+====================+
| Bananas       | $1.34         | - built-in wrapper |
|               |               | - bright color     |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Oranges       | $2.10         | - cures scurvy     |
|               |               | - tasty            |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

- Don't
- mess
- with
- this
- list
- though

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
```

… which gets converted to this TeX file with `pandoc -s -V documentclass=memoir blah.md -o blah.tex`:

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}

\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}lll@{}}
\caption{Sample grid table.}\tabularnewline
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.20\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Fruit
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.20\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Price
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.27\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Advantages
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.20\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Fruit
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.20\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Price
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.27\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Advantages
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.20\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Bananas
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.20\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
\$1.34
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.27\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  built-in wrapper
\item
  bright color
\end{itemize}
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.20\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Oranges
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.20\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
\$2.10
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.27\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  cures scurvy
\item
  tasty
\end{itemize}
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Don't
\item
  mess
\item
  with
\item
  this
\item
  list
\item
  though
\end{itemize}

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

\end{document}
```

And finally produces this document:

[image: final document]

I've found a couple possible solutions, but they don't work—the space remains:

- Put cells inside `minipage`s and do something with `\@minipagetrue`, since [that should make it so `itemize` doesn't add vertical space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6445/preventing-itemize-environment-to-insert-initial-vertical-space). Pandoc already wraps each of the cells inside a `minipage`, but the vertical space still appears.
- Use `\package{enumitem}` and `\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt}` to [globally remove spacing above all lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86055/11851). However, this is not specific to only lists inside tables (and it doesn't modify this list anyway).

---

So, in the end, how can I remove the space before and after `itemize` lists inside `minipage`s that are inside `longtable`s **without** directly modifying the table itself (i.e. only adding or modifying commands and macros in the preamble)

Comment: Is it an option for you to use an own column type for that purpose (removing some space from the top) or are that mixed-content columns?

Comment: For an own column type see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352597/124577

Comment: What is the purpose of the 24 [!] instances of `\strut`? Without the struts, the spacing is just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must confess I don't understand the purpose of the 24 `\strut` directives. Without them, and without any changes to the `itemize` environment itself, the table looks like this -- which, I assume, is close to what you want. (Note that the code bloat isn't trimmed either.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}

\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\hrule
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}lll@{}}
\caption{Sample grid table.}\tabularnewline
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.20\columnwidth}\raggedright
Fruit
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.20\columnwidth}\raggedright
Price
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.27\columnwidth}\raggedright
Advantages
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.20\columnwidth}\raggedright
Fruit
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.20\columnwidth}\raggedright
Price
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.27\columnwidth}\raggedright
Advantages
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.20\columnwidth}\raggedright
Bananas
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.20\columnwidth}\raggedright
\$1.34
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.27\columnwidth}\raggedright
\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  built-in wrapper
\item
  bright color
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.20\columnwidth}\raggedright
Oranges
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.20\columnwidth}\raggedright
\$2.10
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.27\columnwidth}\raggedright
\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  cures scurvy
\item
  tasty
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Pandoc generates all the `\strut`s automatically. I wonder if there's a way to redefine struts inside the minipage so they don't do anything to the spacing. Or maybe I just have to filter them out with `sed` or whatever before compiling the document…

Comment: @Andrew - I'm not all that familiar with pandoc. Is it at all configurable? Is there a way to instruct it *not* to insert a veritable blizzard of `\strut` instructions? If you're familiar with `sed`, it should indeed be a piece of cake to eliminate them from the tex file.

Comment: Unfortunately the `\strut`s are all in there by design (see https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/pull/2913). So far the only solution I've found is to remove all `\strut`s that precede `\begin{itemize}` with Perl: `perl -0777 -pe 's/\\strut\n\\begin{itemize}/\n\\begin{itemize}/gm;' blah.tex`. Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: @Andrew - Glad you found a way to eliminate the `\strut` directives in a reasonably efficient way. (Your editing software might also have a global search-and-replace capability.)

Comment: I opened an issue for this (https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3436) and the developers are looking at fixing it. In the meantime, killing all the `\strut`s works great. Thanks!

Comment: This has now been fixed in pandoc: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/f3d81056d66147a42587607a3f8926c0baf06b7e

Comment: @Andrew - Wow, that's really good to know that pandoc's developers are so quick and competent. I read the entire trail of comments and back-and-forth deliberations at the github site -- congrats are also due to *you*, for posting a very clear and actionable initial report that gave the developers a lot to work with. Clearly, posting an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) is helpful not only at TeX.SE! FWIW, your posting 11 days ago featured just such an MWE, and that's what made it straightforward to identify the underlying cause -- the surfeit of `\strut` directives.