# Aligning itemized cell with the rest of the table

Tags: tables, align, itemize

I am a beginner in Latex and I'm trying to learn it to conduct a journal article for Springer. I made a two-column table, with the left column being mostly itemized cells. I'm trying to align the itemized text with the rest of the table's text, but with no results. I'd appreciate some guidance on the matter.

Here is the code I use

```
  \begin{table}[ht] 
        \caption{Applications Overview}
        \label{tab:2}
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.25\columnwidth} p{0.35\columnwidth}}
        \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
        Application Type & Functionality  \\
        \noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
             Environmental & 
             \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
                 \item[] Smart Water Supply
                 \item[] Smart Agriculture
                 \item[] Environment Monitoring
             \end{itemize} \\
             
             Healthcare &
             \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
                 \item[] Heart Rate Monitoring
                 \item[] Blood Pressure Monitoring
                 \item[] Glucometer Monitoring
                 \item[] Real-Time Locationg of Medical Equipment
             \end{itemize} \\
             
             Social & 
             \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
                 \item[] Smart Homes
                 \item[] Smart Surveillance
                 \item[] Smart Mobility
                 \item[] Smart Social Interactions
                 \item[] Smart Shopping
             \end{itemize} \\
             
             Energy Management & Smart Grid \\
             
             Industry 4.0 & 
             \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
                 \item[] Automated Machinery
                 \item[] Smart Manufacturing
             \end{itemize} \\
             
             Industry 5.0 & Synergy of Human and A.I. \\
        \noalign{\smallskip}\hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

And here is the result

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)? I think it is due to the whitespace included before and after the itemize, but I seem to be lacking a package to compile your code...

Comment: If you insist on using a list environment, you can look at [this question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94116/unable-to-remove-vertical-space-before-and-after-lists-within-longtable?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to use a list in this case. The `tabular` envivronment is sufficient:

[image]

#### Notes:

- For table you really should use `booktabs`. I have used that in the MWE below to adjust your rules.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[ht] 
        \caption{Applications Overview}
        \label{tab:2}
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.25\columnwidth} p{0.35\columnwidth}}
        \toprule
        Application Type & Functionality  \\
        \cmidrule(lr){1-2}
             Environmental 
                 & Smart Water Supply \\
                 & Smart Agriculture \\
                 & Environment Monitoring \\[0.75ex]
             Healthcare 
                 & Heart Rate Monitoring \\
                 & Blood Pressure Monitoring \\
                 & Glucometer Monitoring \\
                 & Real-Time Location of Medical Equipment \\[0.75ex]
             Social 
                 & Smart Homes \\
                 & Smart Surveillance \\
                 & Smart Mobility \\
                 & Smart Social Interactions \\
                 & Smart Shopping \\[0.75ex]
             \raggedright
             Energy Management & Smart Grid \\[0.75ex]
             Industry 4.0 
                 & Automated Machinery \\
                 & Smart Manufacturing \\[0.75ex]
             Industry 5.0 
                 & Synergy of Human and A.I. \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```